# Unzipping many files in many subdirectories

Tags: xargs

## BACKGROUND

A directory can  N-sub directories.  Each sub directory contains multiple .rar files to be unzipped.

~/mydi r/Data 1
~/mydi r/Data2
...
~/mydi r/DataN

note the space between the 'i' and 'r' as well as the 'a' and '1'

## GOAL

From the command line, issue a single command to Unzip.rar files and keep files in the original .rar directory (do not create new directories).

My first thought is to recursively build a list of the .rar files direct the output of:

find home/user /mydi\ r/Data\ 1 | grep .rar

into `xargs` and unrar:

```
unrar e -r /home/user/mydi\ r/Data\ 1/myfile.rar
```

## QUESTION

Can `xargs` correctly process space characters in the directory and file names, without the `\` character?

I suspect the space characdters in the directory and .rar filenames are  causing errors with:

```
find /home/user/Desktop/ -name "*Har*.rar" | xargs  -d '\n'  unrar e -r
```

because the `unrar` expects a '\' to precede the space character:

```
/home/user/mydi\ r/Data\ 1/myfile.rar
```

The error returned:  `No files to extract`

Any diagnostic questions or suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

This is why GNU `find` has a `-print0` option and GNU `xargs` has a `-0` option: these options cause `find` to separate filenames with an ASCII `NUL` character, and cause `xargs` to look for a `NUL` character to separate input arguments. This allows you to correctly handle filenames that contain whitespace.

For example:

```
find /home/user/Desktop -name '*.rar' -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 unrar e -r
```

We need the `-n1` flag to `xargs` because `unrar e` expects a single archive on the command line.